# Find $r,q$ so that $Ham(r,q)$ is selfdual and MDS code

Tags: coding-theory

I need to find $r,q$ so that $Ham(r,q)$ is selfdual code and then $r,q$ so that it is a MDS code

**My effort**

$Ham(r,q)= [\frac{q^{r}-1}{q-1}, \frac{q^{r}-1}{q-1} -r, 3] $ code

A code $C$ of length $n$ is selfdual iff $dim C= \frac{n}{2}$

So in this case $\frac{q^{r}-1}{q-1} -r = \frac{\frac{q^{r}-1}{q-1}}{2} $ and this gives me $\frac{1}{2} \frac{q^{r}-1}{q-1} = r $

A linear code $[n,k,d]$ is called MDS if $k+d=n+1$

So in this case $\frac{q^{r}-1}{q-1} -r + 3 = \frac{q^{r}-1}{q-1} +1$, so $r=2$

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Well, you might want to see what specific solutions there might exist for the relationship $\frac 12 \frac{q^r-1}{q-1} = r$ since $q$ must be a prime or a prime power and $r$ must be an integer. In particular, what if $q=2^m$ when the code must have odd length and so the dimension of $\mathcal C$ cannot be half the code length?

Answer (score 2):

$Ham(r,q)= [\frac{q^{r}-1}{q-1}, \frac{q^{r}-1}{q-1} -r, 3] $

A code is self-dual iff it's equal to its dual. 
$S(r,q)= [\frac{q^{r}-1}{q-1}, r, q^{r-1}]$ , so $q^{r-1} = 3$ and that gives us $q=3, r=2$ , the only correct pair.

A linear code $[n,k,d]$ is called MDS if $k+d=n+1$

So in this case $\frac{q^{r}-1}{q-1} -r + 3 = \frac{q^{r}-1}{q-1} +1$, so $r=2$
Finally, $Ham(2,q)= [q+1, q-1, 3]$ is a MDS code.